# Code Coverage TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've made an automated build definition using Team Foundation Server 2012 and added it to the webaccess of TFS2012. The Visual Studio Test Runner also outputs some code coverage results. I can find those results at every build, something like:  80% of all code blocks covered. 
Is there any possibility of adding those code coverage results to my team favorites on the webaccess of TFS2012? The only possibility i found is to write some custom code against the database of TFS (dbo.tbl_ModuleCoverage), but i hope there is a better way to do this.